# IIS Application Initialization with IIS 10.0 and WebAPI

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8, iis-10

Hello and good morning everyone,

I ran into an issue where the services once started, are no longer subscribing to the service discovery. In testing they were running under IIS Express. However once I flipped it over to IIS and verified everything was still working; the service no longer hits the Application_Start() within the Global.asax.cs.

Doing a bit of research, it appears that IIS requires a little configuration to get this to do some initialization work once the Application Pool is started. I am running this in a Windows 10 Professional environment with IIS 10.0.17763.1

The goal: Get the service starting up to subscribe to the service discovery was it was running under IIS Express.

I first found on the MSDN the documentation for setting all of this up including prerequisites here [IIS 8.0 Application Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)

After going through all the steps and updating the required config entries, it appears I am still not Initializing my web service when the Application Pool starts.

I have created a new endpoint on the controller for testing purposes to get this to work.

AccountController:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Init()
{
    // here is where I am registering the service thats coming up
}
```

Route Definition file:

```
{"Name": "Account - Init",
"RouteTemplate": "api/{controller}/init",
"Defaults": "controller = AccountController, action = Init"}
```

Web.config

```
<applicationInitialization skipManagedModules="false" doAppInitAfterRestart="true" remapManagedRequestsTo="/api/account/init">
  <add initializationPage="/api/account/init" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

I am under the assumption that the Initialization will only happen ONCE, and that happens when the Application Pool first starts, or is recycled. IIS internally will make a 'managed' call to the Web Application against the mapped resource it finds in the application's web.config file. Is my understanding of how it should be working incorrect? If so, could someone please clarify why?

I am not simply trying to 'get this to work'. I would like to understand why its 'not' currently working for me.

Thanks to all in advanced who take the time to respond here.

Comment: this is why one should never develop against IIS Express, but against real IIS

Answer (score 0):

that is correct, your web.config will only be read once when the application starts.
you can add some logging messages to see it happen.

You can actually hit debugger points if you manage to connect your Visual studio to the application pool of the IIS process in time. There is an option to attach the debugger to a process, so you can use that.

This is painfully obvious in systems where the AppSettings are in a separate file, not web.config. if you make a change, nothing will happen, until you touch web.config which triggers an application restart.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.

I am able to attach the debugger in visual studio just fine but when the App Pool restarts it kills my session and I have to reattach which is a pain.

However I cannot even verify its hitting the endpoint specified. I do know that the code in the endpoint works, and I have the Gateway / Ingress up in another instance of Visual Studio attached to the w3wp process for 'its' App Pool and I never get any breakpoints.

Which means its not hitting the endpoint I am providing when it starts up.

Comment: in Application_Start, just add some logging text to a file on disk, then you can see if it really isn't getting hit.

Comment: Reporting back, its not writing to disk. Which means its not hitting either Application_Start within the Global.asax.cs or the endpoint I have created in the controller. I put the same code in both places but different text to know where it was logged from.

Answer (score 0):

Following up,

I fixed my own problem. It appears the code IS working correctly, that its hitting the Global.asax.cs Application_Start as it should. I had an exception being thrown not related to IIS after a change I made which was resulting in what appeared to "not work".

Following the instructions on the MSDN does work.